# Undefined error, when exporting a class

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. And I created a demo project using external libraries without using npm. But when I export a class, it shows the error `exports is not defined`
files are

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-   awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

   <!-- SCRIPTS Starts -->
   <!-- EXTERNALS -->

   <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">         </script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"> </script> <!-- 1 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom-server.min.js"></script> <!-- 2 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script> <!-- 3 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script> <!-- 4 -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script> <!-- 5 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.1/axios.min.js">  </script> <!-- 6 -->

  <!-- EXTERNALS -->


  <script src="http://192.168.1.64:5011/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  <!-- Components -->
  <!-- <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/loginComponent.js">   </script> -->
  <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/logoutComponent.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/indexComponent.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/babel" src="react-2.js"></script> -->

   <!-- SCRIPTS Ends -->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="chat-react-app-index"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

`logout.js` error occurs when exporting `logout` class.

```
  console.log("Logout component >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  export default class Logout extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  //this.props.gender = this.state.gender;
  //this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  this.logoutClick = this.logoutClick.bind(this);
  //this.props.logouts = this.props.logouts.bind(this);
  console.log("this.props.loginslogouts");
  console.log(this.props.loginslogouts);
 }

 logoutClick() {
 console.log("logoutClick ============>>>..");
 this.props.loginslogouts(true, false);
 var userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ).username;
 var userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ).userId;
 var userToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')      ).userToken;
var userProfilePic = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')  ).userProfilePic;
io.socket.request({
 method: 'POST',
 url: '/user/logout',
 data: {
   userId : userId,
 },
 headers: {
  'userToken':userToken
 }
}, function (resData, jwres) {
//this.setState({logout: false});
console.log("Logout response -------- >>>>>>............");
console.log(resData);
if (resData.status == 1) {
   console.log("Logout Success");
  localStorage.removeItem("userData");
}
});
}

render() {
return (
 <div id="logoutClick" onClick = {this.logoutClick} className="row">
  <a className="btn btn-primary">LOGOUT</a>
 </div>
)
}

}
```

`index.js`

```
  var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
  var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
  var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
  var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
  var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

  console.log("Index component >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  //import React, { Component } from 'react';
  //require('loginComponent');
  import Logout from './logoutComponent.js'
  class Index extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <div>
         <Logout/>
         INDEX
        </div>
   )
  }

  }

   ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
    <Route path="*" component={Index} />
    </Router>,
   document.getElementById('chat-react-app-index')
  );
```

Comment: Where are you importing "logout.js" or where is your `import Logout from "<yourPath>/logout.js"`? And where is your `ReactDOM.render(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

It's `export` and not `exports`.

Like in `export class MyClass {}`

Comment: I export my class as `export default Logout`

Comment: You should add a code snippet, so everyone can see what you're actually doing